# How to create a regexp that ends in a line break?

Tags: regex, ruby

I have (looong) inputs that are lists of sentences/bullets like the following:

```
Broker and broker´s fees: 不適合

Specific purpose or use for the present acquisition or disposal: 因應內部管理需要，調整投資架構

Other issues to be disclosed: 無
```

In order to "translate" the Chinese text, I want to create objects, in a regexp fashion, so I can later transform the second captured group according to what it says.

I thought something like the following would work:

```
Specific_purpose = /(Specific purpose or use for the present acquisition or disposal: )([.]+)(\n)/
Other_issues = /(Other issues to be disclosed: )([.]+)(\n)/
```

i.e. this regexps should be composed of captured group 1 (the title in English), captured group 2 (the section in Chinese) and the captured group 3, i.e. the new line that indicates where the object ends.

Still, the code does not work and I cannot even get Ruby to find the needed objects in the input. If, for example, I add:

```
if input.include? Specific_purpose.to_s
    puts "Yes, I found such bullet "
else
    puts "No, there is no such bullet"
end
```

I keep getting "No, there is no such bullet", no matter how I rewrite the regexp.

Am I doing something wrong here? How do I create a regexp that will match everything until the line break?

Comment: `$` is the token for end of line.  http://rubular.com is (beyond) handy for validating regexes...

Comment: `[.]+` matches 1 or more dots. `.+` matches 1+ chars other than a newline. Use `.+`.

Comment: Why do you want to capture each newline? If `str` is your string, could you not write `str.split("\n").map { |s| s.split(/: +/) } 
 #=> [["Broker and broker´s fees", "不適合"], ["Specific purpose or use for the present acquisition or disposal", "因應"], ["Other issues to be disclosed", "無"]]`? I suspect I may not fully understand the question.

Comment: @Wiktor, I am perplexed by your criteria for closing a question on the grounds that it is a duplicate of an earlier question. The earlier questions you cite relate to the error the OP made here in trying to solve the current problem, but the questions themselves are unrelated. I've seen many clearly unique questions where the OP's code contained a common error that was no doubt the subject of an earlier question, but that's no reason to conclude that the question itself is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your line contains a colon which also acts as a separator for english and Chinese text, you can use this regex to capture English in group1 and Chinese in group2 to capture the text respectively. Try using this regex,

```
(.+):\s+(.+)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eXCrV1/1)**

Let me know if you face any issues.